# To find the power series of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{4}{3x+2}$ centered at the point $x = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> To find the power series of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{4}{3x+2}$ centered at the point $x = 1$.

$$f(x) = \dfrac{4}{3x+2} = \dfrac{4}{3(x-1)+5}  = \dfrac{\frac45}{1+\frac35(x-1)}. $$

We know that the power series expansion of $$\frac{a}{1-r} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a r^n.$$ Here we take $a = \frac45$ and $r = -\frac35(x-1)$, then the power series of the function $f(x) = \dfrac{4}{3x+2}$ centered at the point $x = 1$ is given as follows

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac45 \left(-\frac35(x-1) \right)^n.$$

Is the derivation correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One minor suggestion is to use properties of exponents to clean up the summand. It is preferable to write

$$f(x)= 4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{3^n}{5^{n+1}}(x-1)^n.$$